# Use same dict inside different classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, global-variables

I have a class named A which has a dictionary named env_vars. I want to access env_var dict in other two classes.

eg.
File-> a.py

```
from b import B
from c import C

class A:
   env_vars = {}

B().print_b()
C().print_c()
```

File-> b.py

```
from a import A
class B:
    def b(self):
        print(A.env_vars)
        A.env_vars['b'] = 2
        print(A.env_vars)

    def print_b(self):
        print(A.env_vars)
```

File-> c.py

```
from a import A
class C:
   def c(self):
        A.env_vars['c'] = 3

   def print_c(self):
        print(A.env_vars)
```

I am able to access A class env_var dict in classes B and C but getting an import error of circular import. How to resolve this error.

Comment: You would use `import a`, not `import A`, to start. `A` would be an *attribute* of `a`. From what you've shown, there is no reason to import `b` or `c` from `a.py`, as `A` doesn't depend on anything in those modules.

Comment: Its because you're also importing B and C on `a.py`.

Comment: In actual implementation, I am using some functions from class B and C.

Comment: Then you need to redesign your modules, and you haven't shown enough of what you *need* for us to help with that.

Comment: If there is a dependency between the three-class, why not put them in the same file? Check [this link](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/) on fixing circular-imports.

Comment: This code looks like it exists solely to demonstrate a circular dependency, not something you would need to write in real life.